# placing two canvases on top of eachother CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to place 2 canvases ontop of eachother, whilst at the same time having them centered like this, but I suspect that one canvas is out of frame.

CSS:

```
body    { background-color: #000000; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width:100%; height:100%; }
*   { margin:0; padding:0; }
canvas  { display:block; padding: 0; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
cnv1    { z-index: 2; }
cnv2    { z-index: 1; }
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="cnv1">U no do HTML5, fix.</canvas>
<canvas id="cnv2">U no do HTML5, fix.</canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var cnv = document.getElementById('cnv1')
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
var cnv2 = document.getElementById('cnv2')
var ctx2 = cnv2.getContext('2d');
```

If I now try to write things like

```
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillText('images loaded and ready to go', 180, 45);
```

then that won't show up. but writing to ctx2 will.

Comment: May I ask WHY you want 2 canvasses? If you design your app correctly you don't need 2 canvasses... Javascript is single threaded anyways. Just have entities that draw themselves on given canvas. Have the entities that  are in the background draw first, then the other entities last.

Comment: It's a performance boost. By placing the background on a separate canvas I don't have to clear the entire canvas and then redraw the background on every loop when I redraw a shape or a picture.

Now I just clear a very small rectangle on another canvas every time I redraw in that area.

This way I save battery power (it's for a mobile app), and take up less processing power.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so turns out it was just me being tired. I just forgot to add # to the cnv1 & cnv2 parts of the css:

```
#cnv1   { z-index: 2; }
#cnv2   { z-index: 1; }
```

It works as intended now. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: But if you didn't written # then how could it work for cnv1 .?

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you want? The back layer and front layer now overlap.
Only thing I had to do for it was to reverse the order in which they appear in the html.

I have no idea why the z-index didn't work/wasn't obeyed. But reversing their order of appearance worked good.

```js
var cnv = document.getElementById('cnv1')
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
var cnv2 = document.getElementById('cnv2')
var ctx2 = cnv2.getContext('2d');


ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillText('images loaded and ready to go', 25, 95);

ctx2.save();

//ctx2.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctx2.clearRect(0,0,ctx2.width,ctx2.height);
ctx2.fillStyle="#eeeeee";
ctx2.fillRect(0,0,50,200);
ctx2.fillRect(50,50,50,150);
ctx2.fillRect(100,0,25,200);

ctx2.fillRect(150,50,50,150);

ctx2.fillStyle="#202020";
ctx2.fillText('Gotham City.', 20, 128);
```

```css
body    { 
  background-color: #000000; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0px; 
  padding: 0px; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; }
*   { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    }
canvas  { 
  display:block; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  background-color:transparent;
  }
#cnv1    { 
  z-index: 2; 
  }
#cnv2    { 
  z-index: 1;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv2">U no do HTML5, fix.</canvas>
<canvas id="cnv1">U no do HTML5, fix.</canvas>
```